# Git blame -M: unexpected behavior

Tags: git, blame

When using git blame -M in order to detect code movements inside one file, I get results which I cannot explain to myself.

First I commit the following file(file.cpp):

```
void func1(){return;}[CR][LF]
int func2(){return 23;}[CR][LF]
```

Then I modify it by moving what was in the first line and adding something new instead:

```
float newFunc(){return 23.0;}[CR][LF]
int func2(){return 23;}[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
void func1(){return;}[CR][LF]
```

The log now looks as follows:

```
>git log --oneline -2
18c670f modified file.cpp
92b4186 added file.cpp
```

Now I run blame:

```
git blame -s -w -M file.cpp
18c670fa 1) float newFunc(){return 23.0;}
92b4186d 2) int func2(){return 23;}
18c670fa 3)
18c670fa 4)
18c670fa 5) void func1(){return;}
```

I wonder why the line containing func1() isn't recognized as moved. I've tried to reduce the number of required characters (i.e. -M4 etc.). Furthermore spaces should not matter because of the -w option.

Answer (score 1):

(3 years later)

> I wonder why the line containing `func1()` isn't recognized as moved.

That could be related to a recently (July 2016) fixed bug for the upcomming git 2.10:

See [commit 17a07e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17a07e2ae2de36cadfac2349189e0c65e1c08d07) (28 May 2016) by [David Kastrup (`fedelibre`)](https://github.com/fedelibre).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7418a6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7418a6b1a056d076b07087bdd27ad51baebc95e0), 19 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `blame`: require 0 context lines while finding moved lines with `-M`
>
> The core part of `git blame -M` required 1 context line, but
>   there is no rationale to be found in the code; it causes artifacts
>   like discussed in [that thread "Understanding behavior of `git blame -M`"](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/255289).
>
> The function `diff_hunks` is a wrapper for the `diff` engine.
>   Putting the context length explicitly into this wrapper (rather than not passing an argument and just setting the context length to zero anyway in the
>   function) clearly indicates that somebody *wanted* it called with
>   different values.
>
> There is no documentation or rationale in the file *why* as far as
>   I remember.
>   Maybe it can crash or end up in an infinite loop.  Maybe it could do so at one point of time but no longer does.
>
> Not sure if it helps, but `ctxlen = 1` seems to be added back in [d24bba8
>   (`git-pickaxe -M`: blame line movements within a file)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d24bba8008d8e537cb48e9760f7621cbe7ae9e38).
>
> Seems like not detecting single line movements is per design and just the documentation is not precise
>   about this. Could such an enhancement be considered as a feature request?

[This thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/295795) sheds some more light on the history of the previous choice.

> The only thing that remotely hints why we thought a non-zero context
>   was a good idea [was this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/28336/focus=28580),  in which I said:
>
> > We may need to use a handful surrounding context lines for better identification of copy source by the "`ciff`" algorithm but that is a minor implementation detail.